# If I want to connect to the database it crashes?

Tags: mysql, xamarin.ios

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using UIKit;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace test.project
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {

        partial void UIButton197_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
        {
            if (textBoxName.Text == "" || textBoxpasswd.Text == "")
            {
                var alert = UIAlertController.Create("Fehler", "Bitte geben sie Benutzername und Password ein", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Ok", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
                PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
                // Fehlerüberprüfung wenn leer ist

            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=8889;database=app;User Id=root;Password=;charset=utf8");

                    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO users(id, username, passwd, rank) VALUES(@user, @pass, @rank)", con);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", textBoxName.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", textBoxpasswd.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rank", 0);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        errorLabel.Text = "ausgeführt";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errorLabel.Text = "no connection";
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    errorLabel.Text = "catch";
                }
            }
        }

        protected ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }
}
```

I try to. connect to the the Database but afte the line con.open the Programm crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is obviously an issue with establishing a connection to the database.

You have defined the server as: `Server=localhost`

Is this absolutely correct? I highly doubt that you are running a full MySQL server on the device itself? If you are running the server on the device, is the server process running?

What is the execption that the application closes with?

`CONNECTION_TIMEOUT`? Probably a firewall issue
`CONNECTION_REFUSED`? The MySQL server process is not running.

You should also design your application to be hardened against database failures, maybe wrapping the connection with a try:

```
try {

    connection.open();

} catch (Exception e) {

    // TODO handle the connection error properly
    System.err.println("An error has occurred.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```